# iconv - differences between R and Linux

Tags: r, iconv

I'm trying to import a tab delimited text file (of weather data) into R.   The main issue seems to be its encoding.   According to Windows notepad, it's UTF-16LE and I'd prefer UTF-8 for importing.

After much fiddling, I've managed to convert it in Linux using iconv:

iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 in.csv -o in_utf8.csv

...which I can then import into r using read_delim with no problems.   Ideally, I would make the conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 a part of the R script that imports and then analyses the data but I can't see how to make R get at a file it hasn't attempted to load.

Thanks in advance
Rob

Comment: I'm not sure what "I can't see how to make R get at a file it hasn't attempted to load" means. Have you looked at the `fileEncoding` argument to `read.table()` (and friends), as well as the `iconv()` R function? If not, see `help("read.table")` and `help("iconv")`. If you have, please [edit] your question to explain why that didn't work

Comment: I've tried that but I don't want to read.table() because I need to fiddle with the column names before I load the table due to some special characters being provided in the field names (the symbol denoting degree of temperature).

Comment: If you need `read_delim()` maybe check out the `locale` argument